# Excel VBA - Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 subs that are run when a certain worksheet is activated within a workbook. However, it fails and I receive the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

The code that errors is:

```
Sub MoveData()
    Dim r As Long, lr2 As Long, lr As Long
    lr2 = Worksheets("Status").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lr3 = Worksheets("Completed").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If lr3 = 1 Then lr3 = 0
        For r = lr2 To 2 Step -1
            If Worksheets("Status").Range("A" & r).Value <> "" And Worksheets("Status").Range("X" & r).Value = "Y" And Worksheets("Completed").Range("A2").Value = "" Then
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 2).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("B" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("C" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("D" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 5).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("E" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 6).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("F" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 7).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("G" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 8).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("H" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 9).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("I" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 10).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("J" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 11).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("K" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 12).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("L" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 13).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("M" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 14).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("N" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 15).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("O" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 16).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("P" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 17).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("Q" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 18).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("R" & lr3)
                Worksheets("Status").Rows(r).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Else:
            End If
        Next r
        For r = lr2 To 2 Step -1
            If Worksheets("Status").Range("A" & r).Value <> "" And Worksheets("Status").Range("T" & r).Value = "Y" And Worksheets("Completed").Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 2).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("B" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("C" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("D" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 5).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("E" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 6).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("F" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 7).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("G" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 8).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("H" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 9).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("I" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 10).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("J" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 11).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("K" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 12).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("L" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 13).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("M" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 14).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("N" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 15).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("O" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 16).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("P" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 17).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("Q" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 18).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("R" & lr3 + 1)
                Worksheets("Status").Rows(r).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                lr3 = lr3 + 1
            Else:
            End If
        Next r
End Sub
```

The highlighted line from debug is:

```
If Worksheets("Status").Range("A" & r).Value <> "" And Worksheets("Status").Range("X" & r).Value = "Y" And Worksheets("Completed").Range("A2").Value = "" Then
```

Would you be able to provide an explanation of why the error is occurring and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: That *whole* code probably doesn't error, just a specific line or two, so which is the line that's highlighted when it errors?

Comment: `If lr3 = 1 Then lr3 = 0`  lr3 cannot be zero - that doesn't resolve to any valid row.  Also you never increment lr3 ?

Comment: @cyboashu Thanks for the link. I will check it out.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've updated the post and indicated the highlighted line and the rest of the code where it's incrementing.

Comment: What's the value of `r` when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the error by removing Range from if:

**Old vba**

```
If Worksheets("Status").Range("A" & r).Value <> "" And Worksheets("Status").Range("X" & r).Value = "Y" And Worksheets("Completed").Range("A2").Value = "" Then
```

**New vba**

```
If Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" And Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 24).Value = "Y" And Worksheets("Completed").Cells(2, 1).Value = "" Then
```

Comment: It's difficult for me to see why those two lines aren't functionally identical...

Comment: I'm struggling to find a link, but what I understood is that range wasn't working because the worksheet wasn't active?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I don't understand why the two expressions aren't functionally identical, but the `Cells` variant worked for me.  In my case also I did not have the referenced worksheet active.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are in Worksheets("Status")

From that error I would imagine it is either zero or one. Has to be 2 or more with your loop

```
For r = lr2 To 2 Step -1
```

Comment: There are 4 rows in the worksheet I am testing with. Once completely populated there will likely never be less than 100 in it at any given moment.

Comment: `UsedRange.Rows.Count` won't return 0 but, even if it did (or if it returned 1), the `For r = lr2 To 2 Step -1` loop would never be entered, and therefore code would never reach the line at which the error occurs.

Comment: Ok. I'm a little confused by that because when I have the Status worksheet active, I do not receive any errors and it accomplishes what I needed it to. From your explanation, I should be receiving errors always with this code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are referring to column values ( A, B, C, D, etc.) when referencing cells (r, 1), (r, 2), (r, 3), (r, 4), etc. rather than the row values, which is what lr2 is initialized to represent. You might be to fix this potential referencing error by reformatting the:

```
Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & lr3 + 1)
Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 2).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("B" & lr3 + 1)
Worksheets("Status").Cells(r, 3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("C" & lr3 + 1
```

To the following code:

```
Worksheets("Status").Cells(1, r).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & lr3 + 1)
Worksheets("Status").Cells(2, r).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("B" & lr3 + 1)
Worksheets("Status").Cells(3, r).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("C" & lr3 + 1
```

Additionally, the `Shift:=xlUp` found in the line:

`Worksheets("Status").Rows(r)`.Delete `Shift:=xlUp`

might be unnecessary, since I think the row that is being deleted is at the bottom of the tabular data.